# Web scraping the steam sale

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I am currently trying to web scrape the steam store sale page however I can scrape all the names and discounts however I do not know how to remove tags from the data

My code is:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

#opening a connection 
my_url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1&os=win').read()


#turning the html into a beautifulsoup object
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(my_url, 'lxml')
def remove_tags(text):
    return ''.join(xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(text).itertext())

data_discounts = (soup.find_all('div', {'class':'col search_discount responsive_secondrow'}))
data_body = (soup.find_all('span', {'class':'title'}))
print (data_body)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for item in data_body:
    print(item.text)  # may need print(item[0].text)
```

Comment: that has worked thank you. Do you have any suggestions for the discount prices

Comment: use Inspect Element in your browser to get the price field's class like you do with the title, then append to the list of titles.